# Get just one database column in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

How is it possible to get the data of just one column in a database table, e.g. title? I'd like to have an array of strings at the end for bootstrap typeahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special method just for that: [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)

```
Post.pluck :title
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database model is called "Post" and the column is "title" then

```
Post.select(:title).all.map(&:title)
```

Will give you an array of all the titles.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
def get_titles
  Yourcolumn.all.each do |i|
    @titles += i.title
  end
  return @titles
end
```

Comment: This is raising an exception: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass